# Constructing the Hessian for a numerical ode solver

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, tensor-products, numerical-optimization, hessian-matrix

I'm working on a project where I need to find the Hessian $\boldsymbol{H}=\frac{\partial^2 \boldsymbol{q}_m}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_0^2}\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n \times n}$ of the function $\boldsymbol{q}_m=\boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{q}_0)$, where $\boldsymbol{q}_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$. For the most easy case, the following scheme can be used to calculate $\boldsymbol{q}_{i+1}$:

$\boldsymbol{q}_{i+1} = \boldsymbol{f}_i(\boldsymbol{q}_{i}) = \boldsymbol{q}_{i} + h\boldsymbol{g}(\boldsymbol{q}_{i})$

where $\boldsymbol{q}_{i}$ is the state vector after the $i$th step, $h$ a constant and $\boldsymbol{g}(\boldsymbol{q}_{i})$ an analytic function $\boldsymbol{g}:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$.

In my application it is relatively easy to find $\boldsymbol{H}_i=\frac{\partial^2 \boldsymbol{q}_{i+1}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_i^2}$ (for 1 solver step), but it's obvious that calculating the full Hessian $\boldsymbol{H} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n \times n}$ becomes rather cumbersome for large $m$.

I've already made quite some attempts to construct the full Hessian $\boldsymbol{H}$, by using the intermediate Hessians $\boldsymbol{H}_i$. As I'm not a mathematician though, I feel I lack some important insights to fully understand what's happpening. In the next paragraphs I'll write down how I want to assemble the full Hessian, but some parts are still vague and not fully understood by myself.

Step 1: Assemble the Jacobian $\boldsymbol{J}=\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_m}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_0}\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, by using the chain rule:

$\boldsymbol{J}=\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_m}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{m-1}}\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{m-1}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{m-2}}...\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{2}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{1}}\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{1}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{0}}$

or

$\boldsymbol{J}=\boldsymbol{J}_{m-1}\boldsymbol{J}_{m-2}...\boldsymbol{J}_{1}\boldsymbol{J}_{0}$

Step 2: In the case of the Hessian, it gets much more complicated. I'll write down my derivation for two solver steps and generalize the solution for $m$ steps:

$\frac{\partial^2 \boldsymbol{q}_{2}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{0}^2}=\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{0}}\right)^{\text{T}}\left(\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{2}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{1}}\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{1}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{0}}\right)$

Applying the chain rule leads to:

$\frac{\partial^2 \boldsymbol{q}_{2}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{0}^2}=\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{0}}\right)^{\text{T}}\left(\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{2}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{1}}\right)\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{1}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{0}}+\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{0}}\right)^{\text{T}}\left(\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{1}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{0}}\right)\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{2}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{1}}$

Inserting the intermediate Jacobian definitions, leads to:

$\frac{\partial^2 \boldsymbol{q}_{2}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{0}^2}=\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{0}}\right)^{\text{T}}\left(\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{2}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{1}}\right)\boldsymbol{J}_0+\frac{\partial^2 \boldsymbol{q}_{1}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{0}^2}\boldsymbol{J}_1$

Changing the order of derivation in the first term yields:

$\frac{\partial^2 \boldsymbol{q}_{2}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{0}^2}=\left[\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{1}}\right)^{\text{T}}\left(\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{2}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{0}}\right)\right]^{\text{T}}\boldsymbol{J}_0+\frac{\partial^2 \boldsymbol{q}_{1}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{0}^2}\boldsymbol{J}_1$

Expanding $\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{2}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{0}}$ results in:

$\frac{\partial^2 \boldsymbol{q}_{2}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{0}^2}=\left[\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{1}}\right)^{\text{T}}\left(\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{2}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{1}}\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{1}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{0}}\right)\right]^{\text{T}}\boldsymbol{J}_0+\frac{\partial^2 \boldsymbol{q}_{1}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{0}^2}\boldsymbol{J}_1$

Applying the chain rule a second time and rewriting the first term between the square brackets gives:

$\frac{\partial^2 \boldsymbol{q}_{2}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{0}^2}=\left[\frac{\partial^2 \boldsymbol{q}_{2}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{1}^2}\boldsymbol{J}_0+\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{1}}\right)^{\text{T}}\left(\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{1}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{0}}\right)\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{2}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{1}}\right]^{\text{T}}\boldsymbol{J}_0+\frac{\partial^2 \boldsymbol{q}_{1}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{0}^2}\boldsymbol{J}_1$

Rewriting the second term between the square brackets leads to:

$\frac{\partial^2 \boldsymbol{q}_{2}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{0}^2}=\left[\frac{\partial^2 \boldsymbol{q}_{2}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{1}^2}\boldsymbol{J}_0+\left[\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{0}}\right)^{\text{T}}\left(\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{1}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{1}}\right)\right]^{\text{T}}\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{2}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{1}}\right]^{\text{T}}\boldsymbol{J}_0+\frac{\partial^2 \boldsymbol{q}_{1}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{0}^2}\boldsymbol{J}_1$

Obviously, this term vanishes because $\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{0}}\right)^{\text{T}}\left(\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{1}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{1}}\right)=0$, which results in:

$\frac{\partial^2 \boldsymbol{q}_{2}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{0}^2}=\left[\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{q}^2_{2}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{1}^2}\boldsymbol{J}_0\right]^{\text{T}}\boldsymbol{J}_0+\frac{\partial^2 \boldsymbol{q}_{1}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{0}^2}\boldsymbol{J}_1$

or

$\frac{\partial^2 \boldsymbol{q}_{2}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{0}^2}=\boldsymbol{J}_0^{\text{T}}\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{q}^2_{2}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{1}^2}\boldsymbol{J}_0+\frac{\partial^2 \boldsymbol{q}_{1}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{0}^2}\boldsymbol{J}_1$

Step 3: For $k$ steps, the equation becomes:

$\frac{\partial^2 \boldsymbol{q}_{k}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{0}^2}=\boldsymbol{G}_k^{\text{T}}\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{q}^2_{k}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{k-1}^2}\boldsymbol{G}_k+\frac{\partial^2 \boldsymbol{q}_{k-1}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}_{0}^2}\boldsymbol{J}_{k-1}$

where $\boldsymbol{G}_k = \boldsymbol{J}_{k-2}\boldsymbol{J}_{k-3}...\boldsymbol{J}_{1}\boldsymbol{J}_{0}$

My questions:

1. Is the above derivation correct? I guess not everything is well-written (in a mathematical sense). But I hope the general concept is ok.
2. How should I interprete the tensor - matrix multiplications (2 terms in the last equation)? I've got some difficulties understanding when/where/why to use the n-mode multiplication. Some clarification would be very helpful!

PS: I'm sorry if some of the above equations are not written well. Feel free to change the notations where requried, as I can always learn more!

Edit: replace the number of steps $n$ by $m$, as I already used the symbol $n$ for the vector/matrix/tensor dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

With tensors of order 3 or higher, the application of matrix-vector products becomes ambiguous. There are several approaches in tensor or Ricci calculus to get the formulas into a compact notation. For Taylor formulas I prefer to write the occurring vector-valued multi-linear forms as directional derivatives in the notation $C(x)[v_1,...,v_k]$ for a tensor that has coefficients depending on $x$, transforming $k$ input vectors into a result vector.

So start with $q_0$ and a perturbation $\delta q_0^{[1]}$, $\delta\approx 0$. Then
$$
q_1+ δq_1^{[1]}+ \tfrac12δ^2q_1^{[2]}+...=f_1(q_0+δq_0^{[1]})=f_1(q_0)+δf_1'(q_0)[q_0^{[1]}]+\tfrac12δ^2f_1''(q_0)[q_0^{[1]},q_0^{[1]}]+...
$$
Next insert the quadratic approximation into the next step
\begin{align}
q_2+ δq_2^{[1]}+ \tfrac12δ^2q_2^{[2]}+...&=f_2(q_1+δq_1^{[1]}+ \tfrac12δ^2q_1^{[2]}+...)\\
&=f_2(q_1)+f_2'(q_1)[δq_1^{[1]}+ \tfrac12 δ^2q_1^{[2]}]+\frac12f_2''(q_1)[δq_1^{[1]},δq_1^{[1]}]+...
\\
\hline
q_2^{[1]}&=f_2'(q_1)[q_1^{[1]}]=f_2'(q_1)[f'(q_0)[q_0^{[1]}]]\\
q_2^{[2]}&=f_2'(q_1)[q_1^{[2]}]+f_2''(q_1)[q_1^{[1]},q_1^{[1]}]\\
&=f_2'(q_1)[f_1''[q_0^{[1]},q_0^{[1]}]]+f_2''(q_1)[f_1'(q_0)[q_0^{[1]}],f_1'(q_0)[q_0^{[1]}]]
\end{align}
The recursion pattern remains stable from now on,
\begin{align}
q_{k+1}^{[1]}&=f_{k+1}'(q_k)[q_k^{[1]}],\\
q_{k+1}^{[2]}&=f_{k+1}'(q_k)[q_k^{[2]}]+f_k''(q_k)[q_k^{[1]},q_k^{[1]}],
\end{align}
expanding the recursion however will lead to really expanded formulas.

Note that in the second derivative the Jacobian is in first place in the first term. Denoting with $J_{n:m}$ the Jacobian of $q_n$ relative to $q_m$ and similarly $H_{n:m}:V\times V\to V$ for the Hessean, one can also write the last as
\begin{align}
J_{k+1:0}&=J_{k+1:k}J_{k:0}\\
H_{k+1:0}&=J_{k+1:k}H_{k:0}+H_{k+1:k}[J_{k:0}\,\cdot,J_{k:0}\,\cdot]
\end{align}
where the single-step variants are $J_{k+1:k}=f_{k+1}'(q_k)$ and $H_{k+1:k}=f_{k+1}''(q_k)$.

---

In the usual Ricci or Einstein tensor notation, every object that transforms **with** the basis is *covariant* and has lower indices, everything that transforms **dual** (also exchanging domain and range) to the basis, like the coordinate functionals, is *contravariant* and has upper indices. Thus a vector $v$ is represented by its coordinate values $v^\mu$, the representation of the Jacobian takes these values and produces new contravariant values, $J^{\mu}{}_\nu$, and the Hessean absorbs two input vectors to produce one output vector, $H^\kappa{}_{\mu\nu}$.
The Einstein summation is the convention that if the same index appears in upper and lower position in a product, then the product is implicitly already a sum over this index over all dimensions.

In this notation the last two identities read as
\begin{align}
(J_{k+1:0})^\mu{}_\nu&=(J_{k+1:k})^\mu{}_\lambda(J_{k:0})^\lambda{}_\nu
\\
(H_{k+1:0})^{\kappa}{}_{\mu\nu}&=(J_{k+1:k})^{\kappa}{}_\lambda(H_{k:0})^{\lambda}{}_{\mu\nu}+(H_{k+1:k})^{\kappa}{}_{\alpha\beta}(J_{k:0})^\alpha{}_\mu(J_{k:0})^\beta{}_\nu.
\end{align}

Comment: As a first exercise, I'm trying to understand all the notations. With respect to the directional derivatives, how should I interprete the term $\tfrac12δ^2f_1''(q_0)[q_0^{[1]},δq_0^{[1]}]$? Or how does it look like in a more expanded form?

Comment: The $δ$ is just a formal infinitesimal parameter to separate the components of different order The second $δ$ is an error from an earlier formulation. For a scalar-valued $f$ you would get $f''(x)[v_1,v_2]=v_1^TH_f(x)v_2$.

Comment: I have some questions w.r.t. to some lines, as well as how to perform some multiplications. 1) In the 2nd line of the 2nd eq., $f_2(q_1)+f_2'(q_1)[δq_1^{[1]}+ \tfrac12 δ^2q_1^{[2]}]+\frac12f_2''(q_1)[δq_1^{[1]},δq_1^{[1]}]+...$, the part $[δq_1^{[1]}+ \tfrac12 δ^2q_1^{[2]}]$ has been replaced by just $[δq_1^{[1]}]$ in the remainder of the derivation. It also hasn’t been used in the term with the 2nd derivative of $f_2$. 2) In the equations for $q_{k+1}^{[1]}$ and $q_{k+1}^{[2]}$, should the subscript for $f_k’$ be replaced by $f_{k+1}’$?

Comment: 3) Where are the dots coming from in $[J_{k:0}\,\cdot,J_{k:0}\,\cdot]$? 4) How are the multiplications $ J_{k+1:k}H_{k:0}$ and $H_{k+1:k}[J_{k:0}\,\cdot,J_{k:0}\,\cdot]$ performed if $J$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and $H$ an $n \times n \times n$ tensor?

Comment: 1) As only the terms linear and quadratic in $δ$ are of interest, terms that obviously lead to a higher degree were left out. 2) Emphatically yes. 3) this indicates the omitted vector arguments, I would have liked a more substantial point, but never found such in the standard LaTeX macros, 4) here $H$ is a vector-valued function, $JH$ is the application of $J$ to the output side of $H$ after evaluation, $H(x)[J·,J·]$ the application of that (different) $J$ to the input vectors before evaluation in $H$.

Comment: I think your answer on my 4th question is definitely the clue of my problem. How can I see that $J$ needs to be applied on the output/input side of $H$? And how does this relate to the tensor n-mode products?

Comment: Using the usual tensor notation, the Hessians have the form $(H_k)^{\kappa}{}_{\mu\nu}$, the Jacobian $(J_k)^\kappa{}_\mu$. The last equation would then be $$ (H_{k+1:0})^{\kappa}{}_{\mu\nu}=(J_{k+1:k})^{\kappa}{}_\lambda(H_{k:0})^{\lambda}{}_{\mu\nu}+(H_{k+1:k})^{\kappa}{}_{\alpha\beta}(J_{k:0})^\alpha{}_\mu(J_{k:0})^\beta{}_\nu.$$

Comment: I tried to modify my original problem to the tensor notation: $\frac{\partial^2 q_2}{\partial q_0^2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial q_0}\left[(J_1)^{\kappa}_{\lambda} (J_0)^{\lambda}_{\nu}\right]$. Expanding this yields $ \frac{\partial}{\partial q_0}\left[(J_1)^\kappa_\lambda \right](J_0)^\lambda_\nu+(J_1)^\kappa_\lambda\frac{\partial}{\partial q_0}\left[(J_0)^\lambda_\nu\right]$. The second term becomes: $(J_1)^\kappa_\lambda (H_0)^\lambda_{\mu\nu}$. How should I deal with the first term in a correct way?

Comment: You need to attach some more indices, $$\frac{\partial^2 q_2^\kappa}{\partial q_0^\mu\partial q_0^\nu} = \frac{\partial}{\partial q_0^\mu}\left[(J_1)^{\kappa}_{\lambda} (J_0)^{\lambda}_{\nu}\right]$$. Then notice that the components of $J_1$ are evaluated at $q_1=f_1(q_0)$, so that you get the chain rule also here, $$\frac{\partial}{\partial q_0^\mu}\left[(J_1(q_1))^\kappa_\lambda \right]=\frac{\partial J_1(q_1)^\kappa_\lambda}{\partial q_1^\alpha}\frac{\partial q_1^\alpha}{\partial q_0^\mu}.$$ Now insert the symbols for the first and second derivative.

Comment: Okay, now it makes much more sense. Before applying the above theory in an example, I have one more question. As I'm not yet fully into the tensor notation, I'm wondering if the subscripts sequence is arbitrary or not. E.g., is $(H_0)^\lambda_{\mu\nu}=?=(H_0)^\lambda_{\nu\mu}$. And if not, why does $\frac{\partial}{\partial q_0}\left[(J_0)^\lambda_\nu\right]$ equal $(H_0)^\lambda_{\mu\nu}$, and not $(H_0)^\lambda_{\nu\mu}$?

Comment: In general it is not arbitrary, but the higher derivatives are symmetric tensors on the input side, so the order in the lower indices does indeed not matter. To be more precise, also the order between higher and lower indices matters, in some situations this can be neglected by the convention that all higher indices are before all lower indices. But that does not work in general.